# Twin Primes Problem: Need Help

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there any twin primes of the form $2^n − 1$, $2^n + 1$, for $n > 2$? If so, can someone give me an example, and if not, can someone prove why there aren’t any.

Answer (score 6):

One of the three numbers $2^n-1,2^n,2^n+1$ is a multiple of 3

Comment: So that is why there aren't any?

Comment: @Megan I'll write a more detailed one.

Comment: $2^n$ is obviously not a multiple of $3$. Therefore one of the other two **must** be a multiple of three. Therefore one of the others **cannot** be prime (apart from the case where $n=2$).

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Thanks, i'll wait for it...

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @Michael 's answer, exactly one of $2^n-1$, $2^n$ and $2^n+1$ is a multiple of $3$.

If it is one of the $2^n-1$ or $2^n+1$, then that particular number is not a prime number (except in the case of $3$, which is why $n=2$ works). So, it will have to be $2^n$ which is a multiple of $3$, which is not possible.